# App Removed - APK HAS A PRIVACY POLICY​ BUT IT IS NOT ADEQUATE

Tags: android, google-play

App is removed by Google because of "APK HAS A PRIVACY POLICY​ BUT IT IS NOT ADEQUATE"

[image]

Can someone help for hint to fix it? Thanks.

Version code is over 50 and it is the first time issue by the play console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the same issue. Probably your app has privacy policy link which open browser and download your pdf file. If it, try change pdf to html which will just open in browser